# AngularJS $http ajax not working on asp.net web api call

Tags: ajax, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple AngularJS ajax call as follows.

```
    $scope.modelObject.sendRequest = function (requestType) {
        var dataTemp = { first: 7, second: 3 } ;
        alert($httpParamSerializer(dataTemp));
        $http({
            url: '/api/bindings/sumnumbers',
            data: $httpParamSerializer(dataTemp),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }
        ).success(function () {});
    }
```

And at the other end I have a web api BindingsController with sumnumbers action method as follows.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SumNumbers() {
        if (Request.Content.IsFormData()) {
            NameValueCollection jqData = await Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
            int firstValue, secondValue;
            if (TryGetValues(jqData, "first", "second", out firstValue,
                out secondValue)) {
                return Ok(firstValue + secondValue);
            } else if (TryGetValues(jqData, "value1", "value2", out firstValue,
                out secondValue)) {
                return Ok(firstValue - secondValue);
            }
        }
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

The alert in the javascript code `alert($httpParamSerializer(dataTemp));` is showing the data correctly.
And a break point I placed in the action method is hit showing that the call is successiful. But the problem is TryGetValues(jqData ... is not not able to get any values. Is see that `AllKeys` property of `jqData`(NameValueCollection), does not have any keys at all!!. Can someone please suggest what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a petty mistake from my side. Just need to add

```
method:'Post'
```

inside the call so the call becomes

```
        $http({
            method:'Post',
            url: '/api/bindings/sumnumbers',
            data: $httpParamSerializer(dataTemp),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }
```

I used the fiddler to find this out.